# How to program a script that changes url

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, url, tampermonkey

I want to make a tampermonkey script that basically changes the url of the page. What I want to do is to look if the url has "youtube.com" in it and if it doesn't then it should add /youtube.com to the url.

An example of this is:

The starting website: www.website.com/watch8dzjad8

The changed website: www.website.com/youtube.com/watch8dzjad8

If it helps then the script is meant to be finished in tampermonkey, so that on a specific website it is going to scan for the link and add the /youtube.com if it can't find it since it won't work otherwise and it would really help me to not to copy and paste /youtube.com 10 times a day, as well as to learn how to work with URL's in JavaScript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( !location.host.match(/youtube.com/) )
   location= "/youtube.com"+ location.pathname
```

But instead of that you should restrict this behaviour to a specific site, not just all domains that are not youtube, for example:

```
if( location.href.match(/website.com\/watch/) )
   location= "/youtube.com"+ location.pathname
```

**Explanations**

location.href.match(/website.com/watch/)

- **location.host** is the domain of the page (www.website.com)
- **location.href** is the complete URL of the page (http://www.website.com/watch8dzjad8)
- **match** tests if the string follow the given pattern

location= "/youtube.com"+ location.pathname

- setting location implies opening the given URL
- **location.pathname** gives the path of the URL (/watch8dzjad8)

So if the URL (http://www.website.com/watch8dzjad8) of the visited page contains the string "website.com/watch", then open "/youtube.com" + "/watch8dzjad8".

As the domain is the same, a relative URL is enough, the browser knows that is the same domain as the current page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: it worked amazingly, but it works too well and it constantly adds /youtube.com. Really thankful for the first bit of code though, could you explain it what does it do part by part ?

Comment: That's why I gave you then a better approach!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't realized thanks a lot for all the help it has really helped me out :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function getQueryValue( myUrl ){
      myUrl = newUrl.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]" + myUrl + "=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( location.href);
      if( results == null )
        return "";
      else
        return results;
    }

    //current url 
    var curUrl = location.href;

        //new url 
        var newUrl = getQueryValue( "curUrl" );

        //redirect to new page
        location.href = newUrl;
    }
```